# "App crashed" Django and Node together on Heroku

Tags: django, node.js, heroku, deployment, dyno

I followed this post

[enter link description here](https://engineering.heroku.com/blogs/2014-10-29-heroku-django-node)

All the display goes without errors, but the logs. says this.

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"
```

My django project has the following structure .

```
**djangoproject**
  |--settings.py
  |--wsgi
**djangoapp**
manage.py
package.json
server.js
**node_modules**
Procfile
Procfile.web
requirements.txt
```

The content for WSGI:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "djangoynode.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

The content for Procfile:

```
web: bin/runsvdir-dyno
```

The content for Procfile.web:

```
django: gunicorn djangoynode.wsgi
node: node server.js
```

The content for .buildpacks:

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python.git
```

also I have .

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
```

I am a beginner , thank you in advance for any help or correction for something to help me remove the error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760612/heroku-at-error-code-h10-desc-app-crashed-method-get-path-favicon-ico

Comment: the problem is usually beacuse your wsgi file is not configured properly.Check the heroku docs to see how it should be.

Comment: Thanks for the replies . But if we display a normal normal django project is unfolding well for what is the wsgi not zero , but assumed it was something about integrate it with node in Procfiles climbed specifically why specific content of those files.